# Можно ли подключиться к эмулятору Android с API Level 25+ запущенному в Windows из виртуальной машины macOS?

Tags: android-studio, macos, vmware, android-emulator

Даны:

- ПК под управлением Windws 10 с Android Studio
- OSX 11, запущенная в vmware c Android Studio
  Запустить эмулятор Android на гостевой операционной системе не представляется возможным, поскольку отсутствует поддержка VT. Хотелось бы подключиться к эмулятору, запущенному в Windows. Пробовал пробрасывать порты в настройках NAT Virtual Network Editor VMWare, и подключаться посредством ADB. Однако безуспешно. Это невозможно, или я что-то делаю не так?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
>adb connect 192.168.1.5:5555
Connection refused

>adb devices                 
List of devices attached
192.168.1.5:5555        offline
```